# Upload image with UploadField in frontend form Silverstripe 4.0

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm not able to upload pictures through the front end form in Silverstripe. I have looked at the example on this [page](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/) but it didn't help me. Updating text fields is working fine. My code is posted below, what have I missed?

```
public function ChecklistForm()
{
    $checklist = Checklist::get()->byID($this->request->param('ID'));

    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        __FUNCTION__,
        FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Object','')
                ->addExtraClass('form-control')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder','Object')
                ->setAttribute('value', $checklist->Object),
            TextField::create('Contact','')
                ->addExtraClass('form-control')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder','Contact')
                ->setAttribute('value', $checklist->Contact),
            TextField::create('Address','')
                ->addExtraClass('form-control')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder','Address')
                ->setAttribute('value', $checklist->Address),
            HiddenField::create('ChecklistId','')
                ->setAttribute('value', $this->request->param('ID')),
            UploadField::create('Images','Upload Images')
                ->setFolderName('checklist-images')

        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('handleChecklist','Update Checklist')
                ->setUseButtonTag(true)
                ->addExtraClass('btn btn-default-color btn-lg')
        ),
        RequiredFields::create('Object','Contact','Address')
    )
    ->addExtraClass('form-style');

    return $form;
}

public function handleChecklist($data, $form)
{
    $checklist = Checklist::get()->byID($data['ChecklistId']);

    $checklist->Object = $data['Object'];
    $checklist->Contact = $data['Contact'];
    $checklist->Address = $data['Address'];
    $form->saveInto($checklist);
    $checklist->write();

    $form->sessionMessage('Checklist has been updated!','good');

    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

Comment: I don't think UploadField works in the frontend… you might have to resort to a `FileField`

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can choose an image but when I'm pressing submit button the image isn't saved.

Comment: Well, at least in the posted code, there is nothing to handle the upload and save the image anywhere

Comment: @NicoHaase Can you please point me in the right direction on how to handle this?

Comment: Haven't worked with silverstripe in a while, but just as you added formdata to the model in `handleChecklist`, you should read the image data from the request and put it in the filesystem

Comment: I see there is a module called https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-dropzone/tree/master/code that can handle file upload on frontend form, but it's not ss4 yet unfortunately

Comment: You may still interested in uploading image from frontend page, I have developed [this module](https://packagist.org/packages/hudhaifas/silverstripe-frontend-fields) for Silverstripe 4, which allows drag and drop + preview. `$field = FrontendImageField::create('Photo', 'Photo', $object->Photo());`

Comment: @Hudhaifa Great that you have developed a module for uploading images in frontend since core doesn't support this(Talked with the Silverstripe team about it). 

Unfortunately I'm already finished with the project were I wanted to use this feature, "solved" it by using backend instead. But it will probably help people facing same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after:

```
HiddenField::create('ChecklistId','')
            ->setAttribute('value', $this->request->param('ID'))
```

Comment: Seems that the comma only was missing in my posted example, so still the same problem.